# Beyond Compare - can we delete Delete Blank Line while comparing two pdf's text

Tags: beyondcompare4

I am using Beyond compare(version 4) to compare two pdf's text. But in one scenario, since it is comparing Line by Line , if blank comes in middle, it is comparing blank line with other pdf's text , and shows as difference.It follows for the rest of the page. Please see below ,

First PDF

```
Line1: A. Beautiful  
Line2: Blank  
Line3: B. Good
```

Second PDF

```
Line1: A. Beautiful  
Line2: B. Good  
Line3: Blank
```

Kindly let me know, whether we can mark the blank line and delete. so that it will compare only the text.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare doesn't support editing PDF files. However, if it doesn't align text correctly, you can force two lines to align. Right click on a line on the left and select **Align With**, then left click on a line on the right side.